# Regular Expression Question

Tags: regex, lisp

Please help on

1. How to implement a filter box where user can key in search keywords with multiple wildcard characters and at some time user will just use a single wildcard character anywhere from the filter box.
   Examples: M_*_DQ*, *QS1, Reg*, M_*DQ
2. Is it possible to remove/replace duplicated words in a single line by regEx? How to implement this if its possible.
   Example: John, Johnny, John, Doug, Douglas, Doug
   Output: John, Johnny, Doug, Douglas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A regex to match 'M_*_DQ*' will be `/M_.*_DQ.*/`. `.` stands for "any character" and `*` stands for "match 0 or more times". Any special character that the user enters will need to be escaped with a backslash, so for instance if the user entered 'M(_*' this will become `M\(_.*`.
2. A regular expression is not the suitable tool for this.

Comment: Hi Mauritz,  for item#1, its working, i was hoping regEx can help me reduce the number of loops when i try to remove duplicate entries in my list, thanks anyway